# Generate a new maven property from an existing one

Tags: maven

We need a new property  `scala.major.version` that is extracted from an existing property `scala.version` by removing the minor version number at the end  E.g.

> 2.11.8 =>  2.11

The approach that I have tried is to use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` and apply a `\\.[\\d]+$` regex pattern using `regexPropertySettings` as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>regex-property</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
     <regexPropertySettings>
        <regexPropertySetting>
                <name>scala.major.version</name>
                <value>${scala.version}</value>
                <regex>\\.[\\d]+$</regex>
                <replacement></replacement>
                <failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>
        </regexPropertySetting>
     </regexPropertySettings>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is the invocation

```
mvn -X -Dscalatest.version=2.2.6 -Dscala.version=2.11.8  
     -Dspark.version=2.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Djava.version=1.8 validate package
```

However it seems that this task were not executed: I do not even see any substitution taking place.

So what is the correct tool to achieve the property generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checking the [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) shows that your plugin's configuration isn't correct

Your command line works with this pom.xml. At least in the debug you can see the message:

```
[DEBUG] define property scala.major.version = "2.11"
```

this is a pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>37957533</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>regex-property</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>regex-property</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>scala.major.version</name>
                            <value>${scala.version}</value>
                            <regex>\.[\d]+$</regex>
                            <replacement></replacement>
                            <failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Nope. The `<regexPropertySettings>` allows multiple entries to occur. In addition I'm not completely certain whether one or two backslashes required - but have already tried both.  The above will not work.

Comment: @javadba - please update your ticket with your pom.xml and the command line

Comment: @javadba - never mind, but please post your pom.xml and your command line. The code you've posted in the question doesn't work, so I assume you are doing something that doesn't run validate phase at all

Comment: I'll need to provide a trimmed pom.xml for that - it's after 2am will do later. But the mvn command line was appended to the OP.

Comment: @javadba - I've posted a whole pom.xml that works with your command line.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the [`regex-property`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-property-mojo.html) goal with the [`regex-properties`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-properties-mojo.html) goal. The first will only replace a single value whereas the latter can replace multiple values (with the help of the[`regexPropertySettings`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-properties-mojo.html#regexPropertySettings) parameter).

Also, the regular expression you pass as the `regex` parameter does not need to be Java-escaped, the plugin will do it. As such, the correct regex to pass will be:

```
<regex>\.\d+$</regex>
```

which will select the minor version number (all digits after the last dot). The regex parameter will be inside a [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) so that what is captured can be replaced by the configured replacement.

#### With `regex-property`

In your case, you are only interested in replacing a single value so `regex-property` is appropriate. The configuration would be:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>regex-property</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>scala.major.version</name>
                <value>${scala.version}</value>
                <regex>\.\d+$</regex>
                <replacement></replacement>
                <failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The execution is directly configured with the wanted values. This will correctly create the wanted property `scala.major.version`.

#### With `regex-properties`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>regex-properties</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>regex-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <regexPropertySettings>
                    <regexPropertySetting>
                        <name>scala.major.version</name>
                        <value>${scala.version}</value>
                        <regex>\.\d+$</regex>
                        <replacement></replacement>
                        <failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>
                    </regexPropertySetting>
                </regexPropertySettings>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This time, since this goal can target multiple replacments, it is needed to define each of them inside a `regexPropertySetting`. The result will be the same.

Comment: I did not confuse the two: I used the second form to be prepared in case we need additional properties down the line. But putting in a single property is not disallowed.  Both double and single escaped were attempted and neither works. When using maven debug I di not even see anything happening related to regexPropertySettings or scala.major.version: is there something required ? The documentation says it were supposed to run in the `Validation` phase -but no evidence of it in the debug output.

Comment: The info on the escape not being required is helpful so I will upvote. But the fact that the whole operation does not even seem to be executed is a mystery.

Comment: @javadba Well I ran both configuration with the given regex and it was correctly invoked when running `mvn validate`. Running `mvn -X validate`, I have the logs `[DEBUG] define property scala.major.version = "2.11"`. How are you running Maven?

Comment: Added the mvn invocation line.

Comment: @javadba Then I cannot reproduce your issue. Are you sure this isn't inside a `<pluginManagement>` section? Or inside a profile that isn't activated?

Comment: @javadba (Oh I started by saying there was a confusion since you're using the `regex-property` goal but using the configuration of the `regex-properties` goal. That could have been a typo).

Comment: <replacement></replacement> can't be empty )

Comment: guys, could someone help me with my issue? I need to transform a main class property from format _abc.def.ghi.ClassKt_ to _src/main/kotlin/abc/def/ghi/Class.kt_
I thought I could do it in 2 steps, first replace `(\w+)(\.)` with `$1/` and then `(.*\/.*)Kt` with `src/main/kotlin/$1.kt`
even if I did it with one regex, it still seems I cannot use this new property in another plugin (maven-enforcer-plugin, goal enforce, configuration rule requireFilesExist)